# Shared eigen vectors of Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix

### Note: this question is still unanswered! (I will provide an answer if I come to one on my own).

#### Background

Say we have a continuous twice differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We know that this function has a symmetric, positive definite Hessian matrix, $\nabla^2 f$. This Hessian can be decomposed as,

$$\nabla^2 f = R \Lambda R^T, $$

where $\Lambda: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix of eigen valuaes and $R:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a matrix of eigen vectors. Note that here $\Lambda$ and $R$ are themselves functions of the arguments to $f$.

#### Question

Given the function $f$ has a Hessian with decomposition $R \Lambda R^T$, is there a way to compute all functions $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that,
$$\nabla^2 g = R D R^T, $$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix?

#### Updates:

- John provided a method for computing $g$ so that its Hessian has the correct decomposition at a chosen point. Unfortunately this does not hold over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:
$$
g(v) = f(v) +  v^t R(D - \Lambda)R^t v + h(v),
$$
where $h$ is *any* function with $\nabla^2 h = 0$.

I'm assuming that you either mean $\nabla^2f(0)$ is $R\Lambda R^t$, and simply omitted the argument "0", or you mean for $R$ and $\Lambda$ to be parameterized by the argument to $f$, in which case mine will need that as well.

Comment: Thanks John! I did mean that $R$ and $\Lambda$ should be parameterized by the argument to $f$ -- I'll make this more clear in my question.

Comment: In that case, we need $\nabla^2 h = 0$ everywhere, which makes $h$ be an affine function. Other than that, my answer stands.

Comment: I think I've missed something. If we choose $\Lambda =0$, we would expect $\nabla^2 g = 0$. I think this is only the case if $R D R^T $ is constant with respect to $v$ in the solution you've provided. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: I thought that $f$ was given, so $\Lambda$ is completely determine by $f$. But I think that I probably DID miss something here: things I assumed were constant (like R and $\Lambda$) are varying, so computing derivatives involves the product rule which I ignored. So...my answer is good at a single point, but not over all of $\Bbb R^n$. I'll rethink later.

Comment: Thanks, John. I appreciate it.